# Como "startar" um servidor Node?

Tags: windows, node.js

Instalei o Node, criei a variável de ambiente (`NODE_ENV`) valor development.

Quando instalei e configurei, imprimi um `arquivo.js` com hellow world e funcionou.

Hoje, quero iniciar o servidor, mas não consigo. Já fiz set `node_env` e a variável de ambiente está ok.
Já digitei no terminal `node -v`, mas não mostra a versão, o Windows não reconhece este comando.

Como faço para iniciar e manter o servidor Node em execução?

Comment: Não uso muito a formatação de textos, pois sou deficiente visual e não é possível acompanhar visualmente cada formatação, estilo, etc. O que poço fazer é escolher fonte, cor, coisas mínimas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provavelmente, apesar de você criar a variável NODE_ENV, ela não está no PATH do Windows, isso é necessário para que o Windows reconheça o comando que vc está executando, no caso o node -v.

Faça isso nas propriedades avançadas do sistema, na aba Avançado, variáveis de ambiente.

Outra opção, é setar isso via linha de comando, faço isso com um BAT, para simplificar o processo, assim só seto as variáveis quando realmente preciso. Abaixo um exemplo de como ficaria o BAT:

```
SET NODE_ENV=<caminho_node>
SET PATH=%PATH%;%NODE_ENV%
```

Note que neste caso as variaveis de ambiente serão validas apenas para a sessão atual. Então faça o BAT, salve no diretório de trabalho do node, e antes de começar a rodar o node, execute o bat.

Answer (score 3):

No windows o node disponibiliza o arquivo nodevars.bat que atribui ao PATH o caminho para funcionamento do NodeJs e NPM.

**C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs** ou **C:\Program Files\nodejs**

Para manter a aplicação rodando você pode utilizar o Forever ou PM2.

https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

https://github.com/foreverjs/forever

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção para criar um servidor sem muita dificuldade é usar os módulos: express-generator no node.

O express-generator pode ser instalado ao digitar o comando:

```
$ npm install express-generator -g
```

Criando a estrutura do projeto:

```
$ express exemplo-express -e ejs
```

Uma estrutura semelhante a essa será criada no seu diretório raiz.

```
exemplo-express/
├── bin/
├── public/
│   ├── images/
│   ├── javascripts/
│   ├── stylesheets/
├── routes/
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── users.js
├── views/
│   ├── error.ejs
│   ├── index.ejs
├── app.js
├── package.json
```

Depois disso, será preciso instalar todas as dependências que se encontram em  package.json.

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Papa instalar as dependências basta digitar no console o seguinte comando:

```
$ npm install
```

Feito isso, seu servidor já estará criado e pronto para ser usado e o server pode ser iniciado com o comando:

```
$ npm start
```